# in Terminal, what is the difference between normal mode and switching to bash?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

When you are in Terminal, you are greeted with a prompt saying:

> computer_name:~ directory user$ *(command input)*

Then if you use the command *"bash"*, the prompt changes to:

> bash-3.2$ *(command input)*

Now I understand that when you use a command like *"python"*, you are taken into the Python interpreter, but it seems like pretty much all the same commands as usual work when you switch to Bash. Could someone explain what (if anything) is happening here?

Comment: Perhaps the default shell is not bash? Run `ps -p $$` or `echo $0` in a terminal to find out.

Answer (score 1):

When you type `bash` you are taken into a new `Bash` instance. If you press `Ctrl + D` you will exit. OSX uses Bash as default shell.

Comment: Ok, so there really is no difference, as you are already in Bash when you start up Terminal?

Comment: There's no difference.

Comment: yes, it's just that your $HOME/.profile has a line that changes the "layout" of the command prompt variable, which is call `$PS1`. Good luck to all.